# Showing that a function has a minimum on a non compact interval

Tags: real-analysis, limits

The question states: Let $f: (-1,1) \rightarrow R$ be cts and suppose $\lim_{x \to -1} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \infty$. Show that $f$ has a minimum on $(-1,1)$

My attempt:

Given $\lim_{x \to -1} = \infty$, we have $f(x) > M$ for all $M$ when $x > N_{1}$. Similarly, $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \infty$ implies that $f(x)>M$ for all $M$ when $x>N_{2}$.

Since $f$ is cts, it has a minimum on all compact intervals by the Maximum Theorem. Take the interval $[N_{1},N_{2}] = I$, then there exists an L s.t. $f(x) \geq L$ for all $x \in I$. If x $\notin I$, take $M = L$. So we have $f(x) \geq L$ for all $x$ which completes the proof.

Is my logic correct here?

Comment: You never say who $N_1$ and $N_2$ are; that paragraph is wrong, in part because you seem to be confusing limits *at* infinity with limits *go* to infinity. It is also wrong that “$f(x)>M$ for all $M$ when...” because that would require $f(x)$ to be larger than all real numbers, and no such number exists.

Comment: Order matters. What you meant in that paragraph is: for *each* $M>0$ there exists $\epsilon_{1,M}>0$ such that if $-1< x < -1+\epsilon_{1,M}$, then $f(x)>M$. Similarly, for each $M>0$ there exists $\epsilon_{2,M}>0$ such that if $1-\epsilon_{2,M}<x<1$, then $f(x)>M$.”

Comment: (Order in that you first specify $M$, then you specify the conditions on $x$, not the other way around). The basic *idea* can be made to work, but since you never specify what $N_1$ and $N_2$ are, and you don’t place them correctly inside of $(-1,1)$, what you write does not actually work. In addition, your $L$ is only asserted to be a lower bound, so you have not proven that it has a minimum, just that it is bounded below.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument does not make much sense. What do mean by $x >N_1$ and $x >N_2$. You are not taking limits as $ x \to 1$and $x \to -1$.

Here is a valid argument: let $\alpha =\inf \{f(x): -1<x<1\}$. Note that $\alpha \leq f(0) <\infty$. The hypothesis tells you that if $\delta \in (0,1)$ is sufficiently small then $f(x) >\alpha$ when $x \in (-1,-1+\delta)$ and also when $x \in (1-\delta, 1)$. Now I leave it to you to verify that the minimum of $f$ on the compact interval $[-1+\delta, 1-\delta]$ is also the minimum of $f$ on $(-1,1)$.